# Why does this Constructor with no arguments seem to be a problem for this code?

Tags: c++

I can't compile this code. It seems that the problem is with the constructor of the Friends class, but I can't understand where the problem is.

I tried to remove it and it compiled successfully, but the default constructor doesn't seem to work as well.

Here is what the compiler shows:

```
UnNamed.cpp: In constructor ‘Friends::Friends()’:
UnNamed.cpp:92:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘Friend::Friend()’
   Friends() {
             ^
UnNamed.cpp:52:3: note: candidate: Friend::Friend(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)
   Friend (string n, string c): Person (n, c) {
   ^~~~~~
UnNamed.cpp:52:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
UnNamed.cpp:41:7: note: candidate: Friend::Friend(const Friend&)
 class Friend: public Person {
       ^~~~~~
UnNamed.cpp:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
UnNamed.cpp:41:7: note: candidate: Friend::Friend(Friend&&)
UnNamed.cpp:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Date{
  int d;
  int m;
  int y;
};


class Person{

protected:
  string name;
  string surname;

public:
  Person(){
    name = "xxx";
    surname = "xxx";
  }

  Person (string n, string c) {
    name = n;
    surname = c;
  }
  string get_surname() {
    return surname;
  }
  void print (ostream& f_out) const {
    f_out << name << " " << surname;
  }

};




class Friend: public Person {

private:
  Date bdate;
  string email;

  bool bissextile( int a ) {...}

  bool check_date() {...}

public:
  Friend (string n, string c): Person (n, c) {
    email = "xxx";
    bdate.d = 1;
    bdate.m = 1;
    bdate.y = 1;
  }

  void set_date (int d, int m, int y) {...}

  void set_email (string e) {
    email = e;
  }

  void print ( ostream& f_out) {
    f_out << name << " " << surname << " " << bdate.g << "/" << bdate.m <<"/" << " " << bdate.a << "/" << " " << email;
  }


};



class Friends {

private:

  Friend friend_list[100];
  int i;

public:

  Friends() {
    i = 0;
  } 

  void add(Friend a) {
    string err = "Out of space";
    if ( i == (100 - 1) )
      throw err;

    friend_list[i] = a;
    i++;
  }


  void print (ostream& f_out)  {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      friend_list[j].print(f_out);
  }

};
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code (the first refers to `Person`, the second `Persona`).

Comment: `Friend` doesn't have a zero-argument constructor, and you need a zero-argument constructor to initialize an array in `Friends`. Since you provided one constructor, compiler will no longer generate the default constructor for you.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry, I tried to "translate" all the variables for english speakers and I forgot to change that one!

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This is pure gold. Thank you!

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Use the answer section to provide answers. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each constructor of a class (`class Friends` in this case) has to initialize each field of that class.

Since `Friends()` doesn't have a member initializer list, each field is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (by default).

For classes, default-initialization just means calling the default constructor, and since `Friend` doesn't have a default constructor (it's not generated automatically since you have a custom constructor), the compiler doesn't know how to initialize `Friend friend_list[100];`.

On the other hand, if you don't provide `Friends()`, the compiler attemps to generate one for you. It fails to do so for the same reason, but for implicitly generated constructors this doesn't result in a error. Rather, `Friends()` gets deleted (the compiler will tell you it's deleted if you try use it).